# Including dict as value in MongoDB mapReduce emit

Tags: javascript, mongodb

For a map function, I have the following code that works:

```
self.url_with_sessions_mapper = Code("""
    function(){
        emit(this.page, {'session':this.session, 'time':this.time});
    }
    """)
```

But for some reason, this doesn't:

```python
self.url_with_sessions_mapper = Code("""
    function(){
        emit(this.page, {this.session:this.time});
    }
    """)
```

I get this error message

```
on namespace test_database.$cmd failed: exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token.
```

Why wouldn't the latter syntax work?

Comment: It is the key in the object `this.session` try `this['session']`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the keys in a dictionary ('associative array') are always being interpreted as strings, never as variable names.
To achieve what I was aiming for, the syntax is:

```
    self.url_with_sessions_mapper = Code("""
        function(){
            var dd = {};
            dd[this.session] = this.time;
            emit(this.page, dd);
        }
        """)
```